# Mobile version issue when domain forwarding with masking

Tags: url-rewriting, mobile, domain

Setup domain to forward to server but when setting the host to forward with masking the mobile version is not loading correctly. When setting domain to redirect without masking (to the IP) the site loads correctly

Screenshots here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyjC.jpg.
Top image is without masking (not IP in search bar) and bottom image is with masking

Don't know if it makes a difference but site is setup as below

**Site Settings**
[image: Site Setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved. Issue was that domain was setup to redirect to IP. What I did that solved the issues was to edit the A record to point to the site IP and removed the domain forwarding. Then was able to set the Wordpress and Site URL to the domain (as suggested in other posts) and all is working fine now